# Retrieving original timestamp after replication using triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, timestamp, replication

Scenario is this: We have two databases db1 and db2. Statements in db1 replicates to db2.

- Query 1 gets executed in db1.
- This is replicated to db2.

Upon execution of replicated query 1 in db2, a trigger needs to run in db2. This trigger needs to update a table in db2, with timestamp of when query 1 was run ***in db1.***

Is this possible?

Comment: When using statement based replication (I'm assuming you are since you have a trigger on the slave only) the time is saved in the binlog and used for `NOW()`'s and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`'s in the queries but I'm not sure for triggers. You can try it easily by stopping the slave for a few minutes and checking the times.

Comment: @Vatev: From [5.0.12 changelog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/news-5-0-12.html) "***Replication***: *[`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now), [`CURRENT_TIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-time) and values generated by timestamp columns are now constant for the duration of a stored function or trigger. This prevents the breaking of statement-based replication. (Bug #12481)*"

Comment: @eggyal I hope that makes sense for OP :)

Comment: Thanks Vatev and eggyal. Will try this out in a few days and confirm...

Comment: Yeah, tested this and it works. The same timestamp is propagated even if replication is delayed.